# Smooth transition between extruded contour line elevations

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I used mapbox studio to create a style . I extrude based on the contour line and the video tutorail found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYGEC7BCHZs&t=26s&ab_channel=Mapbox)

This extrudes based on the elevation of an area. But the result is choppy, looks like steps. How can I achieve the same result but having the elevations smooth transitioning from one to another?

Thank you